# How do I add a tag/label to appear on top of several objects so that the tag always faces the camera when the user clicks the object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Essentially, what I am saying is I want to create a tag or label that appears on top of/on the surface of an object so that the tag always faces the camera when the user clicks the object even when the object is rotated.

How do I go about doing so?

I was told to use Orthogonal camera (but I'm not sure how?) and CSS for the label (see previous post: [How can I make my text labels face the camera at all times? Perhaps using sprites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001208/how-can-i-make-my-text-labels-face-the-camera-at-all-times-perhaps-using-sprite))

The label in CSS and html is below. However, I want to do this for several objects as well, so I guess I can make a list of all the tags I want for each cube in this case.

CSS:

```
label {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color : #99FFCC;
border: 1px solid #008000;
width: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Cube1">
    <label>Cube 1</label>
</div>
```

Previous Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>three.js canvas - interactive - cubes</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
                body {
                        font-family: Monospace;
                        background-color: #f0f0f0;
                        margin: 0px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

                var container, stats;
                var camera, scene, projector, renderer;
                var projector, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }, INTERSECTED;
                var particleMaterial;
                var currentLabel = null;

                var objects = [];

                init();
                animate();

                function init() {

                        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                        document.body.appendChild( container );

                        var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                        info.style.position = 'absolute';
                        info.style.top = '10px';
                        info.style.width = '100%';
                        info.style.textAlign = 'center';
                        info.innerHTML = '<a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - clickable objects';
                        container.appendChild( info );

                        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                        camera.position.set( 0, 300, 500 );

                        scene = new THREE.Scene();

                        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );

                        for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {

                                var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 } ) );
                                object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                                object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                                object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

                                object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
                                object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
                                object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 1;

                                object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                                object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                                object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

                                object.label = "Object " + i;

                                scene.add( object );

                                objects.push( object );

                        }

                        var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
                        particleMaterial = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial( {

                                color: 0x000000,
                                program: function ( context ) {

                                        context.beginPath();
                                        context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0, PI2, true );
                                        context.closePath();
                                        context.fill();

                                }

                        } );

                        projector = new THREE.Projector();

                        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                        stats = new Stats();
                        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                        container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

                        //

                        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                }

                function onWindowResize() {

                        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                }

                function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                        event.preventDefault();

                        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
                        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

                        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

                        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

                        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                        if ( intersects[ 0 ].object != INTERSECTED ) 
                                        {

                                         // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
                                        if ( INTERSECTED ) {


                                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex ); } 

                                        // store reference to closest object as current intersection object
                                        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                                        // store color of closest object (for later restoration)
                                        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                                        // set a new color for closest object
                                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 );

                                        var canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
                                        var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
                                        context1.font = "Bold 40px Arial";
                                        context1.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)";
                                        context1.fillText(INTERSECTED.label, 0, 50);

                                        // canvas contents will be used for a texture
                                        var texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas1) 
                                        texture1.needsUpdate = true;

                                        var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture1, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
                                        material1.transparent = true;

                                        var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(
                                        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas1.width, canvas1.height),
                                        material1



                                );
                                        mesh1.position = intersects[0].point;
                                        if (currentLabel)
                                                scene.remove(currentLabel);
                                        scene.add( mesh1 );                             
                                        currentLabel = mesh1;
                        } 

                        else // there are no intersections
                                        {
                                // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
                                if ( INTERSECTED ) {
                                        console.log("hello");
                                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                                        }
                                        // remove previous intersection object reference
                                        //     by setting current intersection object to "nothing"
                                        INTERSECTED = null;
                                        mesh1 = null; 
                                        mesh1.position = intersects[0].point; 
                                        scene.add( mesh1 );

                                        }






                                //var particle = new THREE.Particle( particleMaterial );
                                //particle.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
                                //particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 8;
                                //scene.add( particle );

                        }

                        /*
                        // Parse all the faces
                        for ( var i in intersects ) {

                                intersects[ i ].face.material[ 0 ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff | 0x80000000 );

                        }
                        */


                }

                //

                function animate() {

                        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                        render();
                        stats.update();

                }

                var radius = 600;
                var theta = 0;

                function render() {

                        theta += 0.1;

                        camera.position.x = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
                        camera.position.y = radius * Math.sin( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
                        camera.position.z = radius * Math.cos( THREE.Math.degToRad( theta ) );
                        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                        renderer.render( scene, camera );

                }

        </script>

</body>
```

Please let me know if I'm being unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not especially familiar with Three.js, but here's the usual steps:

- Choose a point on the surface of your object you want to align the label to.
- Use `projector.projectVector` to get an on-screen point from the in-world point.
- (You may need to scale the result from NDC (-1 to 1) to canvas (0 to canvas.width) coordinates here; I'm not sure.)
- Use the X and Y to set CSS absolute positioning for your label.

Here's code I wrote to do the same thing in my [Cubes](https://github.com/kpreid/cubes) project (not using Three.js, but the principles are the same). It is slightly more complex because what it does is position the element so that it is *next to* an object represented by a set of points (which are provided to the callback passed to `pointGenerator`). It also tries to do sensible things when the object is out of view of the camera.

Feel free to reuse this code and adapt it to your liking.

```
// Position an overlay HTML element adjacent to the provided set of points.
function positionByWorld(element, keepInBounds, pointGenerator) {
  var canvasStyle = window.getComputedStyle(theCanvas,null);
  var canvasWidth = parseInt(canvasStyle.width, 10);
  var canvasHeight = parseInt(canvasStyle.height, 10);

  var elemStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
  var elemWidth = parseInt(elemStyle.width, 10);
  var elemHeight = parseInt(elemStyle.height, 10);

  var slx = Infinity;
  var sly = Infinity;
  var shx = -Infinity;
  var shy = -Infinity;
  var toScreenPoint = vec4.create();

  pointGenerator(function (x, y, z, w) {
    toScreenPoint[0] = x;
    toScreenPoint[1] = y;
    toScreenPoint[2] = z;
    toScreenPoint[3] = w;
    renderer.transformPoint(toScreenPoint);
    toScreenPoint[0] /= toScreenPoint[3];
    toScreenPoint[1] /= toScreenPoint[3];
    toScreenPoint[2] /= toScreenPoint[3];
    if (toScreenPoint[3] > 0) {
      slx = Math.min(slx, toScreenPoint[0]);
      shx = Math.max(shx, toScreenPoint[0]);
      sly = Math.min(sly, toScreenPoint[1]);
      shy = Math.max(shy, toScreenPoint[1]);
    }
  });

  if (shx > -1 && shy > -1 && slx < 1 && sly < 1 /* visible */) {
    // convert to screen
    slx = (slx + 1) / 2 * canvasWidth;
    //shx = (shx + 1) / 2 * canvasWidth;
    //sly = (sly + 1) / 2 * canvasHeight;
    shy = (shy + 1) / 2 * canvasHeight;
    if (keepInBounds) {
      slx = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvasWidth - elemWidth, slx));
      shy = Math.max(0, Math.min(canvasHeight - elemHeight, shy));
    }
    element.style.left   = slx + "px";
    element.style.bottom = shy + "px";
  } else {
    element.style.left   = canvasWidth + "px";
  }
}
```

—[Permalink on GitHub](https://github.com/kpreid/cubes/blob/5a26a35769734a50140a39638ff7e008544b943b/main.js#L107)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ThreeJS documentation for [Sprites](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Sprite).

> A sprite is a plane that always faces towards the camera, generally
> with a partially transparent texture applied.

Also, there are elements called [CSS2DLables](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label), they also face the camera.