# How to pin, rener, an image on an threejs map

Tags: javascript, three.js

So, right now I have a 3D-map (with mouse-interaction) loaded with three.js . I have also placed an image (absolute positioning) "on the map", but of course, when I move the map, the image doesn't move along. 
So, how can I "render', 'pin', ... the image to the map, so it moves along with the camera?

I have been looking into angularjs, css3drendere, but I don't get them working :s

Can someone help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try adding the object as a child of the map: `map.add( object )`. Or, keep the map still and move the camera, instead. If you still have problems, then show a live example of your code and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Would this do the job (for adding them as objects?)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426559/three-js-access-scene-objects-by-name-or-id

Comment: It is difficult to help you without knowing exactly what you are doing. You can edit this fiddle if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/9GudA/.

Comment: I would like somthing like that:
http://dewmap.com/#/experiment/world-connections
or http://www.google.com/zeitgeist/2012/#explore
(The markers on the maps (that move along with the map).
JSFiddle commming up!

Comment: See http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Labeled-Geometry.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it, I searched for hours, but did't found that :D !!

Comment: Maybe I was a little too excited, The example you've given me works if you make a cube,... in three.js, but if you render a json-file (from blender) that doens't work anymore? (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Show a live example of your code and ask a specific question, please.

Comment: I have set the code online:
http://bensjitestsite.site50.net
Sorry for my discourtesy.
What I want is: Markers that 'follow' the map. 
(Now you can see you can move the map, but for my project I am working on, there should be 'points of interest' on that map. (markers that point to a location, when you rotate the map, the markers should follow the map, so they still pinpoint the same location).

Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: 1. You are using a version of the library that is nearly a year old. Please update to the current version. 2. You are not rotating the map, you are rotating the camera. The map is not moving. 3. Where are your markers?

Comment: hihi, I see you are also the guy answering my other questions (a) Thank you for that!

I updated the library, and I also found this post of yours: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001208/how-can-i-make-my-text-labels-face-the-camera-at-all-times-perhaps-using-sprite?rq=1[link], will that do the job for me too?

I don't have any markers (yet), should I make some?

Comment: You can use http://www.google.com/zeitgeist/2012/images/vis/event-location-pin.png for you image and create a `THREE.Sprite` as in http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question so others can benefit.

Comment: ok, I have an other question, but I will open a new topic for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i eventually did it:

```
// ADD SPRITES FOR MARKERS
var pin = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'pin.png' );

var marker = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: pin } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( marker );
sprite.position.set( 1.3, 1.9, -1.7 );
sprite.scale.set(0.2, 0.6, 0.5 );

var marker = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: pin } );
var sprite1 = new THREE.Sprite( marker );
sprite1.position.set( -2.3, 1.9, -1.9 );
sprite1.scale.set(0.2, 0.6, 0.5 );

//Group the markers to set them relative to the map
    group = new THREE.Object3D;
    group.add(sprite);
    group.add(sprite1);
    scene.add(group);
```